# UIRefreshControl Primary Action Triggered not triggering in iOS 8 but triggering in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, ibaction

Is this intended behavior? Is anyone else seeing this? I did drag an outlet directly from the storyboard to the view controller to set up the action so that may be the issue. The only thing is that Value Changed is triggering just fine on both iOS 8 and iOS 9 when created the same way.

Comment: A quick lookup on google would've resolved your doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`primaryActionTriggered`is only available in iOS9.0 and later ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents)). For your action you will need to use other UIControlEvents such as `TouchUpInside`.